# Como adicionar valores a um array de uma matriz em Ruby?

Tags: array, ruby, matriz

```
puts "Alunos\n\n"

alunos = [["Daniel: ", "Nota: 10\n\n"],["Abima: ", "Nota: 10\n\n"], ["Wilame: ", "Nota: 10\n\n"],["Felipe: ","Nota: 10\n\n"]]

puts alunos
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar um novo aluno com uma nova nota como um novo array na matriz acima, de forma que os parametros teriam que ser digitados no terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só usar o método [`push()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-push) que o tipo `array` já dispõe:

```
puts "Alunos\n\n"
alunos = [["Daniel: ", "Nota: 10\n\n"],["Abima: ", "Nota: 10\n\n"], ["Wilame: ", "Nota: 10\n\n"],["Felipe: ","Nota: 10\n\n"]]
alunos.push(["João: ", "Nota: 8\n\n"])
puts alunos
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/d6AASM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hbgtruth-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/ArrayAdd.rb).